# Killing a task doesn't unlock tables in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer version 3.0.04 to interface with an 11g database over a VPN to my company server. I've noticed that after killing a task via the Task Progress window, it does not actually "kill" the task outright. I've read in some forums that what is going on is that Oracle is trying to "roll back" the changes made by the procedure I'm calling, but I can't imagine it's taking more than 10 minutes to roll back to my last commit after 5 minutes of run time. This leads me to believe that it is continuing to run anyway.

I can message the DBA to kill my session, which frees up the lock on the tables the process was using (as well as the source code of the package so I can edit it again), but this is not an optimal solution. I do not have command-line access to the DB, and I do not have administrator privileges through SQL Developer. Is there any way to definitively kill the task I started, a la `kill -9`?

Comment: "I can't imagine it's taking more than 10 minutes to roll back to my last commit after 5 minutes of run time" - Oracle optimises for commit performance, so rollbacks really can be surprisingly expensive.

Comment: I can still just run it for 30 seconds and it will take over 5 minutes (I haven't waited any longer before asking the DBA to kill my session) to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I use this generic thinggy to see whats running in the schema, and use it to monitor
rollback.   It uses concepts stolen from various places on the net, including ask tom.

```
DECLARE

    SID                 INTEGER;
    LOCKWAIT            VARCHAR2(100);
    OSUSER              VARCHAR2(32);
    PROGRAM             VARCHAR2(48);
    LOGIN_TIME          DATE;
    SQL_TEXT            VARCHAR2(32760);
    estimated_rollback_megs     INTEGER;
    STATUS              VARCHAR2(8);

    OSUSERX VARCHAR2(100);
    PROGRAMX VARCHAR2(100);
    SIDX    INTEGER;
    STATUSX VARCHAR2(100);
    MACHINEX VARCHAR2(100);
    LOGON_TIMEX DATE;
    LOCKED_OBJECT_NAME VARCHAR2(100);

    processcount integer := 0;

    CURSOR raw_data IS
        WITH 
            sessionInfo AS
            (
                SELECT *
                FROM V$SESSION
                WHERE USERNAME = USER   -- Just data for my current schema
                ORDER BY SID
            )
            SELECT si.SID,
                   si.LOCKWAIT,
                   si.OSUSER,
                   si.PROGRAM,
                   si.LOGON_TIME,
                   si.STATUS,
                   (
                       SELECT ROUND(USED_UBLK*8/1024,1) 
                       FROM V$TRANSACTION,
                            sessionInfo
                       WHERE sessionInfo.TADDR = V$TRANSACTION.ADDR
                       AND sessionInfo.SID = si.SID

                    ) estimated_rollback_megs,

                    (
                       SELECT (MAX(DECODE(PIECE,  0,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE,  1,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE,  2,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE,  3,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE,  4,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE,  5,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE,  6,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE,  7,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE,  8,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE,  9,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 10,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 11,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 12,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 13,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 14,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 15,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 16,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 17,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 18,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 19,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 20,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 21,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 22,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 23,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 24,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 25,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 26,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 27,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 28,SQL_TEXT,NULL)) ||
                               MAX(DECODE(PIECE, 29,SQL_TEXT,NULL)))    
                        FROM V$SQLTEXT_WITH_NEWLINES
                        WHERE ADDRESS = SI.SQL_ADDRESS AND 
                        PIECE < 30
                    ) SQL_TEXT
            FROM sessionInfo  si;

            CURSOR LONG_OPERATIONS(SIDx number) IS
                SELECT VL.MESSAGE, 
                       VL.START_TIME, 
                       VL.LAST_UPDATE_TIME, 
                       VL.TIME_REMAINING
                FROM V$SESSION_LONGOPS VL,
                     V$SESSION V
                WHERE VL.USERNAME LIKE USER AND
                      V.SID = VL.SID AND
                      V.SERIAL# = VL.SERIAL# AND
                      V.SID = SIDx AND
                      VL.TIME_REMAINING > 0
                ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE_TIME DESC;

message         VARCHAR2(100);
startTime       DATE;
lastUpdateTime  DATE;
timeRemaining   VARCHAR2(100);


PROCEDURE print_sql_statement
(
    printThis IN VARCHAR2,
    Plen  IN NUMBER DEFAULT 132,
    Pwhsp IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT  -- newline+space+tab+comma
             CHR(10) || CHR(32) || CHR(9) || ','
) 
IS
    NL CONSTANT VARCHAR2(1) := CHR(10);  -- newline character (OS-independent)
    SP CONSTANT VARCHAR2(1) := CHR(32);  -- space character
    TB CONSTANT VARCHAR2(1) := CHR(9);   -- tab character
    CM CONSTANT VARCHAR2(1) := ',';      -- comma
    substringStart INTEGER := 1;  -- start of string to print
    substringEnd  INTEGER;       -- end of substring to print
    endOfString  INTEGER := LENGTH(printThis);  -- end of string to print
    newLinePosition    INTEGER;       -- point where newline found
    stringLength       INTEGER := GREATEST(LEAST(Plen, 255), 10);  -- 10 <= len <= 255!
BEGIN

NULL;

END print_sql_statement;


BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Monitor for ' || USER);

    OPEN raw_data;


    LOOP

        FETCH raw_data INTO
            SID,
            LOCKWAIT,
            OSUSER,
            PROGRAM,
            LOGIN_TIME,
            STATUS,
            estimated_rollback_megs,
            SQL_TEXT;

        EXIT WHEN raw_data%NOTFOUND;

        processcount := processcount + 1;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(OSUSER || ' Owns Session ' || SID || ' STATUS ' || STATUS);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Running ' || PROGRAM || ' Since ' || TO_CHAR(LOGIN_TIME,'MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'));

        OPEN LONG_OPERATIONS(SID);

        LOOP
            FETCH LONG_OPERATIONS INTO
                message,
                startTime,
                lastUpdateTime,
                timeRemaining;

            EXIT WHEN LONG_OPERATIONS%NOTFOUND;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('    ' || message);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('    START: ' || TO_CHAR(startTime,'DD HH24:MI:SS')  || 
                                   ' UPDATE: ' || TO_CHAR(lastUpdateTime, 'DD HH24:MI:SS') || 
                                ' REMAINING: ' || timeRemaining);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('    ');

        END LOOP;

        CLOSE LONG_OPERATIONS;

        IF estimated_rollback_megs > 0  then
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Estimated megs of rollback ' || estimated_rollback_megs);
        END IF;

        IF LOCKWAIT IS NOT NULL THEN

            SELECT SID
            INTO SIDX
            FROM V$LOCK
            WHERE ID1 = 
            (
                SELECT ID1
                FROM V$LOCK
                WHERE KADDR = LOCKWAIT
            ) AND BLOCK = 1;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The session is waiting on a lock held by session ' || SIDX);


            select  OBJECT_TYPE || ':' || OBJECT_NAME || ':' || SUBOBJECT_NAME THINGY
            INTO LOCKED_OBJECT_NAME
            from dba_objects
            where object_id =
            (
                select object_id
                from v$locked_object
                where session_id = SIDX
            );

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The locked object is ' || LOCKED_OBJECT_NAME);

            SELECT OSUSER,  PROGRAM,  SID,  STATUS,  MACHINE,  LOGON_TIME
            INTO   OSUSERX, PROGRAMX, SIDX, STATUSX, MACHINEX, LOGON_TIMEX
            FROM V$SESSION
            WHERE SID = SIDX;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SIDX || ': ' || OSUSER || ' Using ' || PROGRAMX || ' STATUS ' || STATUSX);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SIDX || ': LOGGED IN ON ' || MACHINEX || ' SINCE ' || 
            TO_CHAR(LOGON_TIMEX, 'MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'));

        END IF;

        IF SUBSTR(SQL_TEXT, 1, 16) <> 'WITH SESSIONINFO' THEN

            print_sql_statement(SQL_TEXT, 132);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        ELSE
            NULL;
        END IF;

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE raw_data;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(processcount || ' sessions found');

END;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really solve my problem of not being able to kill a task.

Comment: It does solve the problem of answering the question, "Am I still Rolling Back?"